# Multiple joins with where, like and or_like CodeIgniter 3 Active Records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I am trying this:

```
        $location = 'a';
        $this->db->select('l.id, d.guests, l.city, l.country');
        $this->db->from('offers as o');
        $this->db->join('location as l', 'l.id = o.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('desc as d', 'd.offer_id = o.id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('d.guests', $guests);
        $this->db->where('o.completed', 1);
        $this->db->where('l.country LIKE', $location.'%');
        $this->db->or_where('l.city LIKE', $location.'%');
        $this->db->limit(5);
```

And I have offer with 3 guests and with country Albania (1 row per table for it). But, if `$guests = 2;` I have result this 1 row. It is same, if I use `like` and `or_like` instead `where` and `or_where`. If I comment this line:

`$this->db->or_where('l.city LIKE', $location.'%');`

all works fine, I have no results if `$guests != 3` and 1 row result if `$guests = 3`.

Generated query with `$this-db->last_query()` is:

`SELECT 'l'.'id', 'd'.'guests', 'l'.'city', 'l'.'country' FROM 'offers' as 'o' LEFT JOIN 'location' as 'l' ON 'l'.'id' = 'o'.'id' LEFT JOIN 'desc' as 'd' ON 'd'.'id' = 'o'.'id' WHERE 'd'.'guests' = 3 AND 'o'.'completed' = 1 AND 'l'.'country' LIKE 'a%' OR 'l'.'city' LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 5`

How can I make this query ?
Select values where completed = 1, guests = `$guests` and city or country like `$location`.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$location = 'a';
$this->db->select('l.id, d.guests, l.city, l.country');
$this->db->from('offers as o');
$this->db->join('location as l', 'l.id = o.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('desc as d', 'd.offer_id = o.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('d.guests', $guests);
$this->db->where('o.completed', 1);
$this->db->where("(l.country LIKE '".$location."%' or l.city LIKE '".$location."%')");
$this->db->limit(5);
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% or `l`.`city` LIKE a%) LIMIT 5' `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Query grouping](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping)

```
$location = 'a';
$this->db->select('l.id, d.guests, l.city, l.country');
$this->db->from('offers as o');
$this->db->join('location as l', 'l.id = o.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('desc as d', 'd.offer_id = o.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('d.guests', $guests);
$this->db->where('o.completed', 1);
$this->db->->group_start();
$this->db->where('l.country LIKE', $location.'%');
$this->db->or_where('l.city LIKE', $location.'%');
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->limit(5);
```

Also, take a look at the [like and or_like](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data) methods to avoid code like this `'l.country LIKE'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$location = 'a';
 $this->db->select('l.id, d.guests, l.city, l.country');
 $this->db->from('offers as o');
 $this->db->join('location as l', 'l.id = o.id', 'left');
 $this->db->join('desc as d', 'd.offer_id = o.id', 'left');
 $this->db->where('d.guests', $guests);
 $this->db->where('o.completed', 1);
 $this->db->like('l.country',$location,'after');
 $this->db->or_like('l.city',$location,'after');
 $this->db->limit(5);
```